No me ejecuta los programs de python en visual code
Hola a todos soy nuevo en la programacion de payton estoy trando de ejecutar un programa con visual code y no me ejecuta el programa uso la teminal poweshell el codigo es el sigueinte:
def main(): 
 menu = {
              "Baja Taco": 4.00,
              "Burrito": 7.50,
               "Bowl": 8.50,
               "Nachos": 11.00,
              "Quesadillas": 8.50,
              "Super Burritos": 8.50,
            "Suoer Quesadilla": 9.50,
         "Taco": 3.00,
         "Tortilla Salad": 8.00,
         }

ord_total = (0.0,)
while True:
    try:
        item - input("Ingrese un articulo de su pedido:")
    except EOFError:
        break
    item = item.upper()
    if item in "Menu":
        ord - ord_total + "menu"[item]
    elif item == "CONTROL-D":
        print(f"El total de su pedido es ${ord_total:.2f}")
        break
    else:
        print("Articulo invalido")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Hola Héctor ¿A que te refieres con "no se ejecutan"? ¿No puedes invocar al intérprete? ¿o si se ejecutan los scripts pero te genera alguna excepción? ¿Cuál? Tu código tiene varios problemas, para empezar item - input(...) generará un NameError,  debe ser item = input(...), ord_total es una tupla e intentas sumarle un float, if item in "Menu": debe ser if item in menu:, etc,  pero eso no es no es "que no se ejecuten".

Tu código tiene algunos problemas, te dejo la versión corregida:
Nota: Tienes que utilizar la combinación de teclas control + d.
def main(): 
    menu = {
        "Baja Taco": 4.00,
        "Burrito": 7.50,
        "Bowl": 8.50,
        "Nachos": 11.00,
        "Quesadillas": 8.50,
        "Super Burritos": 8.50,
        "Suoer Quesadilla": 9.50,
        "Taco": 3.00,
        "Tortilla Salad": 8.00,
    }

    ord_total = 0.0

    while True:
        try:
            item = input("Ingrese un articulo de su pedido:")
        except EOFError:
            print(f"El total de su pedido es ${ord_total:.2f}")
            break
        item = item.capitalize()
        if item in menu:
            ord_total += menu[item]
        else:
            print("Articulo invalido")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



Buen dia en que parte iria control de por que ustyed le hizo alguna correcione pero cunado le doy copilar el me muesta solo producto invalido y debe de decir que al momento de yo se leccionar un producto me lo meuestre en consola como es, por ejmplo si escojo burrito debe de mostrarme burrito con su precio

Gracias pero al colocar este codigo con la correcion que usted me indica. no se ejecuta completo cada vez que lo voy a copila me muestra ingrerse su pedido y coloco burrito y me dice producto invalido

Tienes que ingresar tal cual esta escrito en el código, si pones con mayusculas o una mezcla con minúsculas con mayusculas no funciona. (Es por tu código)
